# Writing a bot for an online game without screen-scraping or mouse macros

Tags: windows, networking, android, gaming, bots

I want to write a bot that will only send simple commands. The game is an android game which I run in Bluestacks. Game is very simple. The actions the player can take are very limited and the game does not send/receive any data unless the user takes an action, so I believe that the information sent is simple or imitable at least. I don't want this bot to work with screen-scraping and mouse macros because I need to be able to use the computer meantime. So, after some research, I found that I can imitate the information sent by this game. I believe I first need a network sniffing application to examine the packages sent/received. This is the point I could come so far, could you please show me a starting point explaining what to do next? **Which application can I use to examine the transferred information?**

Game is running with an android emulator(Bluestacks) under win7.

Just FYI, I checked the game policy and there isn't anything against this bot, it will neither be abusive nor will make me any profits anyway.

Comment: The networking question itself may be on topic, but the whole development thing is more for [SO]

Comment: I asked this in SO but it was closed because it was not the type of questions that is answered in SO. Then I came here and directly asked the question without searching for it. Apologies for that..

Comment: No, it's fine, that's why we can mark questions as duplicates. It's easy for us if we know the answer already. I'm sure that Stack Overflow would accept your question when it's about something very specific you're trying to do while implementing said bot in whatever language you're planning to use.